# Get the field value in markup?

Tags: entities, theming, nodes

I have 2 fields in a content type.

**field_link** and  **field_hoster**

if in the hoster field *youtube* is selected the markup should embed the linked video.

can you guys give me a example of what i have to write in the markup field?

Comment: #markup is used to set HTML that will be output on the form in drupal

Answer (score 1):

use **hook_form_alter()**

```
$form['field_name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $form['field_name'][#value]
);
```

or you can use prefix or suffix

```
$form['field_name']['#prefix'] = '<div class="field-name"><label>'.$form['field_name']['#value'] .'</label>';
```